# How to set a var if it exists in a dict?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I'm querying an API endpoint which brings information about events. The number of attributes about each event can vary though. I now try to do the following:

```
for e in apiResult:
    event = Event()
    event.street = e['f_street']
    event.price = e['f_price']
    event.venue_name = e['f_venue_name']
    event.start = e['f_start']
    # and about 40 more..
    event.save()
```

But I occasionally get key errors. So for each attribute I need to check whether it exists. I could of course do this as follows:

```
if 'f_street' in e:
    event.street = e['f_street']
if 'f_price' in e:
    event.price = e['f_price']
# etc. etc.
```

but this doesn't seem very Pythonic. Does anybody know how I can (Pythonically) set an attribute to `event`, only if it exists in the `e` dictionary? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Seeing @starrify 's answer, it depends on whether you want to always have the attributes in the `event` object (either with the value from the dict or with None value) or not to have them at all when the key is not in the dictionary. In other words it depends what do you exactly want to do when the key is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to use list of attributes and for loop with if. Something like this:

```
    attrs = ['f_street', 'f_price', 'etc']
    ...
    for e in apiResult:
        event = Event()
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr in e:
                setattr(event, attr, e[attr])
        event.save()
```

This will also eliminate that 40 lines of attribute settings.

Btw, docs on python builtin `setattr` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get` would help:

```
Help on built-in function get:

  get(...) method of builtins.dict instance  
    D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

So you could write like this:

```
# instead of this:
# event.start = e['f_start']
event.start = e.get('f_start') # And it would be None if key not exists
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function for it:

```
def set_if_present(obj, attr_name, dictionary, key):
    if key in dictionary:
        setattr(obj, attr_name, dictionary[key])
```

Than you can use it like this:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> d = {"a": 0, "b": 1}
>>> o = O()
>>> set_if_present(o, "a", d, "a")
>>> set_if_present(o, "b", d, "b")
>>> set_if_present(o, "c", d, "c")
>>> o.a
0
>>> o.b
1
>>> o.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'O' object has no attribute 'c'
>>>
```

or in your case

```
for e in apiResult:
    event = Event()
    set_if_present(event, 'street', e, 'f_street')
    set_if_present(event, 'price', e, 'f_price')
    set_if_present(event, 'venue_name', e, 'f_venue_name')
    set_if_present(event, 'start', e, 'f_start')
    # and about 40 more..
    event.save()
```

To be even more pythonic, you can create a list of pairs like `[('street', 'f_street'), ('price', 'f_price')...]` and go through this one using the pairs to get and set your values.